# How to change language settings of firefox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

How can i change the language settings of FireFox using JavaScript?

I want to set the "intl.accept_languages" to "fr".

It would be very nice if some one can post the code..

Comment: Posted the same question on firefox forum : https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/777237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox 4 you can do this:

```
Components.untils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.setCharPref("intl.accept_languages", "fr");
```

Note: this only works for ASCII preferences. See [nsIPrefBranch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPrefBranch) for more details.

In previous versions of firefox you need to obtain the preference service manually, like this:

```
var rootPrefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
rootPrefs.setCharPref("intl.accept_languages", "fr");
```

Alternatively if you're writing an extension then you can include a default preference file which will override the installation default, although it won't override a user set preference.

Comment: Thanks Neil for your time..I will try in Firefox 4